# How to update status of Celery's tasks in Django?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Friends I have a question: I want to update the status of celery's tasks in Django. An example of what I want:
1- Create a task in tasks say to extract numbers from multiple text files:

```
@shared_task()
def text_analysis():
   #Do this and that
```

2- Create a function in views to upload the files:

```
def text_analysis(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text_files = request.FILES.getlist("files")
        for text in text_files:                         
            text_analysis.delay()
    files = files.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
   return render(request,"demo_demo.html",{"files":files})
```

3- Create a HTML template to view the results:

```
<main>
<form method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" id = "texts_form">
{% csrf_token %}            
<input name="files" type = "file" multiple >
<button type = "submit"> Submit </button>
</form>                 
<div class="table-data">
<div class="order">     
<div class="head">
<h3>Recent Text Files</h3>
</div>                                      
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>                               
<th>Creating Date</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>                        
<tbody>
<div>
{% for file in files %}
<tr>            
<th>    
file name                                                                           
</th>                                                                                                                                                   
<th> 
file status.  ->>>>>>>>>> What I want to do!!!!
</th>                           
</tr>
{% endfor%}
```

I tried many methods like the following:
https://github.com/python-dontrepeatyourself/django-celery-result-backend
https://github.com/testdrivenio/fastapi-celery/blob/master/project/static/main.js

Comment: 1) read https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html. 2) "files":files, files is undefined 3) Your current code makes 0 sense. What are you trying to achieve within the task? It currently neither takes args nor interactes with a cache or a database, so you need to either return smt. or handle the saving logic inside the task to query for it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying to do some text analysis and I am running it using celery. Celery and Redis are working but my issue with displaying task status. The status are dynamic while Django views are static.

Comment: So you want to review the live status? Track the status every second and return it to the frontends context?

Comment: Exactly what I want.